# Can't Enter at if condition and function returns segmentation fault error

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault

This program is supposed to communicate between a client and server trough pipes. The communication already works but I still have two problems:

1. When the user types `compilar -l`, it's supposed to enter at `if(i==1 && strcmp(c,"l")==0)` but it doesn't... If the user types `compilar -c 0`, it enters at the second `if` condition as it is supposed. I don't know why the first if isn't working...
2. If I enter at `listartarefas()` (a while back, the first `if` worked so I could test this) it gives me a segmentation fault error.

Could somebody help me, please?

**Listartarefas() function:**

```
#define TAM_MAX 99

int num = 0;

void listartarefas(Task **tf)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<=(TAM_MAX-1);i++)
  {
    if(tf[i]->tipo == 1)
    {
      printf("Agendada:\n");
      printf("%d\n",tf[i]->identf);
      printf("%s\n",(tf[i]->path));
      printf("%d-%d-%d\n",(tf[i]->ano),(tf[i]->mes),(tf[i]->dia));
      printf("%d:%d:%d\n",(tf[i]->hora),(tf[i]->min),(tf[i]->seg));
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Executada:\n");
      printf("%d\n",tf[i]->identf);
      printf("%s\n",(tf[i]->path));
      printf("%d-%d-%d\n",(tf[i]->ano),(tf[i]->mes),(tf[i]->dia));
      printf("%d:%d:%d\n",(tf[i]->hora),(tf[i]->min),(tf[i]->seg));
    }
  }
}
```

**Main():**

```
int main()
{
  int fd1, fd2;
  int n=0;
  int v =1;
  int i=0;
  char *t;
  char c[2]="";
  Task recebido;
  char buffer[70]=""; //Buffer que guarda o que o cliente envia
  char buffer2[1]=""; //Buffer que guarda o que o servidor envia

  Task tf[TAM_MAX]; //Array de tarefas: onde estão guardadas todas as tarefas introduzidas pelo cliente

  if (access("fifo", F_OK) == -1) //Testa se o ficheiro existe
  {
    if (mkfifo("fifo", 0666) == -1) { //Criar fifo para ler o buffer recebido pelo cliente
      perror("fifo ler");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  if (access("fifo2", F_OK) == -1)
  {
    if (mkfifo("fifo2", 0666) == -1) //Criar fifo para escrever no buffer2 e enviar para o cliente
    {
      perror("fifo escrever");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  if ((fd1 = open("fifo", O_RDONLY)) == -1) { //abrir fifo para ler
    perror("fifo ler");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((fd2 = open("fifo2", O_WRONLY)) == -1) { //abrir fifo2 para escrita
    perror("fifo escrever");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while(1)
  {
    read(fd1,&buffer,sizeof(buffer)); //Lê o que se encontra no buffer
    t = strtok(buffer," -:");  //Vai quebrando o que está no buffer à medida que faz o ciclo infinito

    while( t != NULL)
    {
      if(i==1)
      {
        strcpy(c,t); //Vai copiando o que foi quebrado para c
      }
      if(i==1 && strcmp(c,"l")==0)
      {
        printf("Listar tarefas");
        listartarefas(tf);
      }
      if(i==2 && strcmp(c,"c")==0)
      {
        n=atoi(t);
        v=0;
        cancelartarefa(tf,&num, n);
      }
      t = strtok(NULL, " -:"); 
      i++;
    }
    v=1;
    i=0;

    memset(buffer,0, sizeof(buffer));

    sleep(2);
  }
  close(fd1);
  close(fd2);
  remove("fifo");
  remove ("fifo2");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Well you are only passing in `Task*`. You should really take compiler warnings seriously.

Comment: @leppie But how do I do to solve this? If I change the argument of the function to "Task *tf" it doesn't print correctly

Comment: Because when you use `Task *tf`, there is another warning, that you also ignore.

Comment: I know that there's one warning, I'm just trying to figure out to solve it...

Comment: The segfault comes from the `Task **tf`. If you correctly use `Task *tf` or `Task tf[]`, there should be no errors. Now, I can see that your `Task tf[TAM_MAX]` is never initialized, which probably not what you want.

Comment: @ElderBug Should I initialize it as "Task tf[TAM_MAX] = " " " ? And yes, I've understood that the segmentation fault comes from there, but what should I change inside the function for it to prints correctly if I change the argument to "Task *ff" ?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do ? You print an array of Task, and it works well. What you see printed is the real values of the Tasks, that is, random values, because you never set any value to the Task.

Comment: I do set values to the task, I receive data from the client and and initialize it, I just ommited it from this code to make it simpler. What I want is to print the values inside this array of struct

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't change what I said. From what I see, your function is printing correctly. If it is printing wrong values, that means you set wrong values. This is beyond the scope of this code.

Comment: @ElderBug So, if I just change the argument of the function to "Task *tf" it should still print the correct values? Even if I don't change anything inside the function?

Comment: Yes, your function looks correct if you use `Task *tf` (and `tf[i].members`). It should print the actual values. Now maybe these values are wrong, but that's not because of the printing.

Comment: Use of `read()` and `strtok()` together is highly suspect. `read()` does not null-terminate, nor is it guaranteed to read any particular portion of incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Iffy conditions**

   ```
   t = strtok(buffer," -:");

   while( t != NULL)
   {
     if(i==1)
     {
       strcpy(c,t); //Vai copiando o que foi quebrado para c
     }
     if(i==1 && strcmp(c,"l")==0)
     {
       printf("Listar tarefas");
       listartarefas(tf);
     }
     if(i==2 && strcmp(c,"c")==0)
     {
       n=atoi(t);
       v=0;
       cancelartarefa(tf,&num, n);
     }
   ```

   The first call to `strtok()` returns the first token (the command). At this point, `i == 0` so none of the branches will be taken. Similarly, `i == 1` when you parse the second token (the parameter), so the third branch will not be taken either. You need zero-based indexes:

   ```
   t = strtok(buffer," -:");

   while( t != NULL)
   {
     if(i==0)
     {
       strcpy(c,t); //Vai copiando o que foi quebrado para c
     }
     if(i==0 && strcmp(c,"l")==0)
     {
       printf("Listar tarefas");
       listartarefas(tf);
     }
     if(i==1 && strcmp(c,"c")==0)
     {
       n=atoi(t);
       v=0;
       cancelartarefa(tf,&num, n);
     }
   ```
2. **Faulty function**

   ```
   void listartarefas(Task **tf)
   {
     ...
     if(tf[i]->tipo == 1)
     { 
       printf("Agendada:\n");
       printf("%d\n",tf[i]->identf);
       printf("%s\n",(tf[i]->path));
     ...
   }

   Task tf[TAM_MAX];
   ...
   listartarefas(tf);
   ```

   When an array (`tf`) is used in an expression, it is (with some exceptions) converted to a pointer to its first element. This means that you are passing a `Task *` to `listartarefas()`, but the function expects a `Task **`. This obviously can not work.

   Compilers will inform you about such problems if you compile your code with a healthy set of warnings enabled. With the information you have given us, I suggest that you change your `listartarefas()` function as follows:

   ```
   void listartarefas(Task *tf)
   {
     ...
     if(tf[i].tipo == 1)
     { 
       printf("Agendada:\n");
       printf("%d\n",tf[i].identf);
       printf("%s\n",(tf[i].path));
     ...
   }
   ```
3. **Other observations**

   ```
   read(fd1,&buffer,sizeof(buffer)); //Lê o que se encontra no buffer
   ```

   You never test the return value of `read()`.

   ---

   ```
   while(1)
   {
     ...
   }
   ```

   You don't seem to have a way to exit this loop.

   ---

   ```
   strcpy(c,t);
   ```

   There is only room for one character and a terminating zero in `c`, but you never check the length of the token `t`. This could easily cause a buffer overrun.